# Неисправный поиск на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет!

Написал вот такой обработчик событий на `<input>` строки поиска:

```
searchInp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase().trim();
const trList = document.querySelectorAll('.table-body-items tr td');
let trArr = Array.from(trList);

if (searchString != '' ) {
  trArr.forEach (elem => {
     if (elem.innerText.toLowerCase().trim().search(searchString) == -1) {
        elem.classList.add('hide');
        
     }else {
        elem.classList.remove('hide');
     }
  });
}else {
  trArr.forEach (elem =>{
    elem.classList.remove('hide');
  });
 }
});
```

Поиск идет и он находит нужный мне элемент, но он удаляет класс `hide`, только после того как я полностью сотру вводимые данные из строки input'a.

Например, есть названия, которые содержат `Air`. Если добавлю к строке поиска какую-нибудь лишнюю букву, типа `Airr` или `Airru` то соответственно ничего не находит. Но когда я стираю до `Air` я ожидаю, что он покажет все элементы с такой подстрокой - но вместо этого ничего. А вот когда ещё одну букву стираю , типа было `Air` и стираю букву `r` (оставив в строке инпута `Ai`), то он вновь показывает элементы.

Как сделать так, чтобы он проверял не только каждый раз, когда я ввожу строку, но и когда стираю данные из строки input?

Comment: В код особо не вникал, но по-моему тут разумнее слушать событие `input`, а не `keyup` - по ряду причин (одной из которых является и эта "проблема", если она связана с тем что предполагаю причиной).

Comment: @yar85 Здорова, да действительно, теперь появилась какая реакция ,когда стираю, но после нескольких повторов , проблема снова появляется

Comment: _«после нескольких повторов , проблема снова появляется»_ - такое может происходить из-за падения скрипта (при ошибке выполнения). Когда проблема снова проявится, открой консоль браузера и проверь отсутствие ошибок в ней.

Comment: @BearVorkuta да

Comment: @yar85 скрипт не падает, т.е. он работает, он почему-то когда например: есть названия ,которые содержат Air и я вот добавлю какую-нибудь лишнюю букву, типа Airr или Airru и соответственно ничего не находит, но когда я стираю до Air я ожидаю , что он покажет все элементы с таким названием, но вместо этого ничего, а вот когда ещё одну букву стираю , типа  было Air и стираю букву - Ai осталось, то он вновь показывает элементы, надеюсь поняли)

Comment: Вот это лишнее let trArr = Array.from(trList); И как уже посоветовали - лучше событие input использовать. А так вполне рабочий код

Comment: Автор, добавь в вопрос запускаемый пример, в котором эта проблема повторяется (в редактировании вопроса нажми Ctrl+m, затем в открывшийся редактор помести разметку и кодом, и **убедившись что проблема воспроизводится**, сохрани изменение вопроса). Без воспроизводимого примера тут похоже никак не разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> searchInp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
> ```

```
searchInp.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
```

Comment: ТС в комментарии к вопросу писал что это не решает проблему  И во всех проверенных мной браузерах (при одиночных нажатиях клавиши) `value` инпута считывается одинаково что при `keyup`, что при `input`. Хз как воспроизвести его баг...

Comment: @yar Спасибо, брат, проблему пока не знаю как решить , уже запарился , думаю , сяду позже и к вопросу или в новом вопросе как положено покажу проблему

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос. Но если я понял его правильно, то нужно повесить слушатель не на событие 'keyup' -  а на событие 'change'.

Comment: Привет, но я сам input то не меняю, а только его значение, т.е. на такое событие он не будет реагировать, пробовал